# Imagesharp - prevent from resizing small images

Tags: imagesharp

Is it possible to prevent Imagesharp from resizing images if their dimensions are smaller than those specified in the query parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [`ImageSharp.Web`](https://github.com/sixLabors/ImageSharp.Web) then yes.

You would have to replace the default [`ResizeWebProcessor`](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp.Web/blob/5901fff5dc3d216817779d3ac1739fa78f7d86b1/src/ImageSharp.Web/Processors/ResizeWebProcessor.cs#L69) with an updated version of `Process(FormattedImage image, ILogger logger, IDictionary<string, string> commands)` that first checks the size parsed from the command against the input image.

Comment: Yeah, I meant ImageSharp.Web. But thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help!